# Type error: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, opencv

I was trying the code on colab, and this is part of my code

```py
    while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret:
                frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                cls_idx = int(frames_label[frames_label['frame'] == i]['label'])
    
                if annot:
                    bb = np.array(annot.iloc[i-1, 2:].astype(int))
                else:
                     
                    bb = detector.detect(frame)[0, :4].numpy().astype(int)
                bb[:2] = np.maximum(0, bb[:2] - 5)
                bb[2:] = np.minimum(frame_size, bb[2:] + 5) if bb[2:].any() != 0 else bb[2:]
```

I also use imshow() to show the picture on my screen(it is not on the code above due to the code's length), the pictures can show correctly at first, but it will stop at a particular picture, and raise

```
Type error: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable at 

bb = detector.detect(frame)[0, :4].numpy().astype(int)
```

p.s. bb is the abbreviation of bounding box

Error Image:

[image: Error Image]

can anyone help please? Thank you

Comment: From your code it seems like you're getting frames from a webcam, it's possible that either the `frame` that is the image itself is not being recorded by the webcam, or `detector.detect()` is outputting `None`. You might want to check both of those. Could you possibly link the code for `detector`?

Comment: The code is too long to add comment, this is the link of the code I use https://github.com/GajuuzZ/Human-Falling-Detect-Tracks/blob/master/DetectorLoader.py

Comment: I couldn't understand all of what the code does, but it looks like you don't deal with the possibility of `detect` being `None` in the code. You process `detect` if it's not `None` but if it is, it's being returned either way. One solution would be to surround `bb = detector.detect(frame)[0, :4].numpy().astype(int)` with a try except and `continue` to the next loop if it errs

Comment: when I use print(frame), there are numbers printed out, but when I use detector.detect(), it is outputting None.

Comment: yup, then it's because your `detect` is returning `None` because you haven't dealt with it in your code

Answer (score -1):

I can't completely test this, but make these changes and let me know if it works:

```
try:
    bb = detector.detect(frame)[0, :4].numpy().astype(int)
except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e)
    continue
```